# Autorotate Landscape/Portrait View

Tags: ios, image, orientation, autorotate

I'm working on a gallery where I want to rotate the view automatically based on the pictures orientation. So for example, two photos:

- 1200w x 800h pixels
- 550w x 800h pixels

Now to determine which is **portrait**, I just need to check `if height > width`? Is that the only way? Can someone suggest a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your technique to determine if the image is in portrait seems nice and simple. Is there some reason you're reluctant to use that approach? Hard to think of a more logical solution.

By the way, rather than rotating the view if the picture's orientation is different than the screen, in my gallery I personally default to "aspect fill" if my image's height-to-width ratio is close to the aspect ratio of the current view (I think my threshold is 10%), and I use "aspect fit" otherwise (and I also give them a user interface for toggling between aspect fit and aspect fill, or better yet you could offer pinch-zoom). If the user wants to rotate the device to change orientation to maximize the experience, they can, but I'm personally not a fan of forcing them to do so unless there is some extremely compelling to do so (i.e., the app just couldn't possibly function in the other orientation).